# Div centering issue

Tags: html, css, centering

I hope someone can help me and that I'm doing this right...

I am fairly new to HTML, CSS and the alike with little over a year's experience, this being the first website I am coding by hand - my previous attempt was using Wordpress.

Anyway, I will try and make this post as detailed as possible...here we go! :)

I'm trying to center my main div with an id of wrapper. My issue is when I use `margin: 10px auto;` it centers it perfectly regardless of my PC's resolution or the zoom level of my browser. Then, when my browser window is re-sized the wrapper div starts moving around, going over my navigation bar - here are the CSS rules that apply to both the wrapper div and navbar;

```
#wrapper {
   width: 850px;
   margin: 10px auto;
   padding: 10px;
   background: white;
}

#nav {
   padding: 5px;
   position: fixed;
   left: 35px;
   top: 250px;
}
```

Now, when I get rid of the `margin: 10px auto` and use `margin: 10px 250px` the div is almost center for my resolution and browser zoom, but when I zoom out it shifts the entire page to the left but my window re-sizing problem is gone....

Any help or advice would be most welcome!

Comment: Paste some HTML markup or JSFiddle example, please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm asuming that the content is flowing over your navigation that is placed to the left as a sidebar?
In that case just add `margin-left: 200px`(note: change 200px to the width of your navigation) to your wrapper div like so:

```
#wrapper {
   width: 850px;
   margin: 10px auto;
   padding: 10px;
   background: white;
   margin-left: 100px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

My original answer will not center the wrapper div.
What you can do is to add another div inside `#wrapper` and add all background styles and so on to this.
Then you can center the wrapper div using `margin:auto` and add a left padding to avoid having it overflow your navigation.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cPL7/2/)

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding-left: 100px;
    width: 850px;
}

#wrapper .content{    
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
}

#nav {
    padding: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 35px;
    top: 250px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod...</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="nav">
    navigation
</div>
```

Another solution could also be adding a padding to the body, although this will affect your entire page(i.e. footer and header and so on)

```
body{padding-left: 200px;}
```

Comment: This will overwrite the `auto`-value assigned to the left and right margins in the declaration `margin: 10px auto`, so the wrapper will no longer be centered.

Comment: I just realised that this would be an issue. I will update my answer soon.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for all the suggestions! I will try them, and if they don't work I will share my site via dropbox if anyone wants a look... :)